# Multiple 3D surface plots in plotly for R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, plotly, surface

This may have been asked before and I've even used the online tutorial available for plotly here: https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/#multiple-surfaces

But I am still having issues. I want to create multiple surfaces on one plot just like in the tutorial I linked above. The only difference is that I have 4 small matrices as follows:

matrix 1 (line313C):

```
0.521025641 18  0
0           25  0
0.914285714 18  1
0.328461538 25  1
```

matrix 2 (line832C):

```
0.63        18  0
0.38        25  0
0.99        18  1
0.251578947 25  1
```

matrix 3 (line730C):

```
0.107222222 18  0
0.21        25  0
1           18  1
0.549226006 25  1
```

matrix 4 (line380C):

```
0.13        18  0
0.01        25  0
0.933918129 18  1
0.938421053 25  1
```

Using the following code:

```
cold3Dplot <- plot_ly(showscale = FALSE) %>%
  add_surface(z = ~line313C) %>%
  add_surface(z = ~line380C, opacity = 0.98) %>%
  add_surface(z = ~line730C, opacity = 0.98) %>%
  add_surface(z = ~line832C, opacity = 0.98)

cold3Dplot
```

I get this:

[image]

Not even close to what I was expecting. The axes ranges do not even look right at all as one should be between 0 and 1, one between 18 and 25, and one from 0 to 1 (whole numbers - actually 0 or 1). Moreover, there is only 1 surface, not 4. I am not entirely sure what the issue is as I followed the tutorial.

############# EDIT:

I was able to create this plot using wireframe in R:

[image]

using this data:

```
line    surv        temp    stage
313     0.521025641 18      L
313     0           25      L
313     0.914285714 18      A
313     0.328461538 25      A
832     0.63        18      L
832     0.38        25      L
832     0.99        18      A
832     0.251578947 25      A
730     0.107222222 18      L
730     0.21        25      L
730     1           18      A
730     0.549226006 25      A
380     0.13        18      L
380     0.01        25      L
380     0.933918129 18      A
380     0.938421053 25      A
```

and the following code:

```
wireframe(surv~stage*temp, data=cold3D_top4, group=line, 
      col.groups=c("red","green","blue","purple"),
      scales = list(arrows=FALSE, col="black",font=10),
      xlab = list("Life Stage",rot=30, mgp=c(2)),
      ylab = list("Rearing Temperature",rot=-40),
      zlab = list("Survival",rot=90),
      zlim = c(0,1),
      ylim = c("18","25"),
      par.settings = list(regions=list(alpha=0.75)))
```

This is what I want just in case my description didn't make any sense. Is there a way to do this in plotly?

Comment: I just realized that plotly is using col and row names to make dimensions on the graph. could be one reason, working on finding a solution but not having any luck

Comment: That didn't get to the problem